# JavaScript: Unable to break out of for of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-of-loop

I am working on this simulation ([link to example](https://jsfiddle.net/718BkQns/st79d2g5/2319/)) of a Mars rover represented by a object/class. You are supposed to be able to give it inputs of directions based on the terrain of Mars and get a output in the form of a JavaScript Object which will update you how the rover is progressing through the terrain.

I've worked out the other conditions but my problem is trying to work out the logic for when the rover hits a mountain or crevice.

These are the data types used with the rover object/class based on the terrain.

```
const TERRAIN_TYPES = {
  'P': {
    obstacle: false,
    description: 'plains'
  },
  'M': {
    obstacle: true,
    description: 'mountains'
  },
  'C': {
    obstacle: true,
    description: 'crevasse'
  }
};

const STATUS_CODES = ['OK', 'OBSTACLE', 'INVALID_COMMAND'];

// top left corner is (X:0, Y:0)
// bottom right is (X:4, Y:4)
const WORLD = [
  ['P', 'P', 'P', 'C', 'P'],
  ['P', 'M', 'P', 'C', 'P'],
  ['P', 'M', 'P', 'C', 'P'],
  ['P', 'M', 'P', 'P', 'P'],
  ['P', 'M', 'P', 'P', 'P']
];

const DIRECTIONS = ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W'];
const COMMANDS = ['L', 'R', 'F', 'B'];
```

This is the object/class`enter code here` I created.

```
class Rover {

  constructor(location, direction) {
    this.location = location
    this.direction = direction
    this.commands = []
  }

  positionPossible(value) {
    return TERRAIN_TYPES[value].obstacle
  }
 
  command(commands) {
    this.commands = [...this.commands, ...commands];
    if (COMMANDS.indexOf(this.commands[0]) == -1) {
      return {
        status: STATUS_CODES[2],
        loc: this.location,
        dir: this.direction
      }
    }
    return this.roverController()
  }

  roverController() {
    const TURN_LEFT_CMD = COMMANDS[0];
    const TURN_RIGHT_CMD = COMMANDS[1];
    const MOVE_FORWARD_CMD = COMMANDS[2];
    const MOVE_BACKWARD_CMD = COMMANDS[COMMANDS.length - 1]

    const commands = this.commands
    let res = {
      status: null,
      loc: this.location,
      dir: this.direction
    }

    if (DIRECTIONS.indexOf(this.direction) !== -1) {
      
      for (let element of commands) {
        if (element === TURN_LEFT_CMD) {
          this.direction = DIRECTIONS[DIRECTIONS.length - 1];
          res = {
            ...res,
            ...{
              status: STATUS_CODES[0],
              loc: this.location,
              dir: this.direction
            }
          }
        }
        if (element === TURN_RIGHT_CMD) {
          this.direction = DIRECTIONS[DIRECTIONS.length - 2];
          res = {
            ...res,
            ...{
              status: STATUS_CODES[0],
              loc: this.location,
              dir: this.direction
            }
          }
        }
        if (element === MOVE_FORWARD_CMD) {
          if (this.positionPossible(WORLD[this.location[0]][this.location[1]]) === false) {
            this.location[1] = this.location[1] = this.location[1] - 1;
             res = {
              ...res,
              ...{
                status: STATUS_CODES[0],
                loc: this.location,
                dir: this.direction

              }
            }
          } else {
           if (this.positionPossible(WORLD[this.location[0]][this.location[1]]) === true) {
          
            this.direction = (commands[commands.indexOf(element - 1)] === 'L') ? 'E' : 'W'
            this.location[1] = this.location[1] = this.location[1] + 1;            
            return res = {
              ...res,
              ...{
                status: STATUS_CODES[1],
                loc: this.location,
                dir: this.direction

              }
            }
  break
          }
        }
        }
        if (element === MOVE_BACKWARD_CMD && !this.positionPossible(WORLD[this.location[0]][this.location[1]])) {
          this.location[1] = this.location[1] = this.location[1] + 1;
          res = {
            ...res,
            ...{
              status: STATUS_CODES[0],
              loc: this.location,
            }
          }
        }

      }
      return res
    }
  }
}
```

You'll notice I made a function `roverController()` which contains some enums for certain data conditions and a `for-of` loop which is going over the commands created and spits back a response object for feedback e.g.

```
let res = {
   status: null,
   loc: this.location,
   dir: this.direction
 }
```

And as it hits the conditionals, I update the response object with the changing statuses,

This is the condition which should give me the error that the rover hit impassable terrain :

```
  if (this.positionPossible(WORLD[this.location[0]][this.location[1]]) === true) {
              
                this.direction = (commands[commands.indexOf(element - 1)] === 'L') ? 'E' : 'W'
                this.location[1] = this.location[1] = this.location[1] + 1;            
                return res = {
                  ...res,
                  ...{
                    status: STATUS_CODES[1],
                    loc: this.location,
                    dir: this.direction
    
                  }
                }
      break
              }
            }
```

I would think the return (or the break) statement would kick one out of the function and return the status object but it doesn't;

Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: a `break` statement surely will break the for..of cycle.  `const a=[1,2,3]; for(var i of a){ console.log(i); break; }` will only print 1. Your error should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

`break` terminates the loop where it is executed. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

`return` followed by a value exits a function returning the value to the statement that originally called the function. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Personally, to aid readability, I like any `return` statement to be the last statement within a function. So, a good structure would be:

```
...

  for (...) {
    if (whatever) {
    returnValue = ...
    break; // loop exits regardless of conditional;
    }

  } // end for loop;

return returnValue; // returnValue set in loop before break;

} // end function
```